# Does a PoA network use gas?

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-authority

I understand PoW uses gas to counter a DDoS attack. What about PoA? Is gas also used in PoA networks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof of Authority networks still use gas to power Contract calls and Transactions.

Answer (score 0):

EVM-based PoA chains use gas because gas is an integral part of the EVM. Other PoA chains might use different spam protection mechanisms or--in setups where the authorities trust each other as well as all transaction senders--go without one altogether.